# VS 2010 debugger having problems with enums?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, enums

I am thinking of making an enum for my permissions types instead of storing them all as true or false values in db.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test addEdit = Test.AddEdit;
        bool hasEdit = addEdit.HasFlag(Test.Edit);
        bool hasAdd = addEdit.HasFlag(Test.Add);
        bool hasDelete = addEdit.HasFlag(Test.Delete);
        Console.WriteLine(hasEdit);
        Console.WriteLine(hasAdd);
        Console.WriteLine(hasDelete);
        Console.Read();
    }
}

   [Flags]
    public enum Test
    {
        Add = 0,
        Edit = 1,
        Delete = 2,
        AddEdit = Add | Edit
    }
```

So I made this. The funny thing that I found is that addEdit varaible shows only the value of "Edit" when looking at it through the VS debugger. At first I thought it was not storing both values.

I used the hasFlag method and sure enough it knows about both values.

So is it a bug or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx) mentions that all values in enums with `[Flags]` should be in powers of 2 (i.e. `1,2,4,8.....`).

You can assign 0  if you have a `'None'` enumeration.

Check the section titled "**Guidelines for FlagsAttribute and Enum**" in [[Flags]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx) documentation.

When you OR a value with zero (`0`), result will be the same value again. So, in your case,  '`AddEdit`' will result in to '1' which represents '`Edit`' in the '`Test`' enum.

Answer (score 5):

`AddEdit== Edit == 1`. So debugger does not know if you want to convert 1 to "Edit" or "AddEdit".

Most likely you want

```
[Flags] 
public enum Test 
{ 
    None = 0,
    Add = 1, 
    Edit = 2, 
    Delete = 4, 
    AddEdit = Add | Edit 
}
```